# Datatables with added select form

Tags: html, ajax, datatables

here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

HTML

```
<select id="office-select" name="idOffice">
     <option value="">All</option>
     <option value="1">Berlin</option>
     <option value="2">New York</option>
     <option value="3">Tokio</option>
</select>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

After I choose office (for example New York) from select form, I want to dynamically reload the content of the table from file '../ajax/data/arrays.txt?idOffice=2'

How can I do it? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
$('#office-select').on('change', function(){
   $('#example').DataTable().column(2).search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/qg4nhmp1/) for code and demonstration.